# getting issue in update query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, updates

Guys i am facing an issue in laravel on update i want to update 2 values in single column but its update only one value i want to update both values please help also please see my code and image link also for better understanding

Thanks
here is my code:

```
         \DB::table('subscriptions')->where('business_id', $business_id)->update(array('package_details' => $package['name'],'package_details' =>$package['location_count']));
```

here is the image 
please see the 430 id in image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/33azI.jpg

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Take a look at [updating json columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#updating-json-columns)

Comment: i want output like id 430 same as it but it is only update one value not all as i mention in my query

Comment: right now i am getting output you can check id 318

Comment: this query is also not working as i want

$update = \DB::table('subscriptions') ->where('business_id',$business_id) ->limit(1) ->update( ['package_details' => $package['location_count'+'user_count'+'product_count'+'invoice_count'+'name'] ]);

Comment: @digisoft check my answer

Comment: dear your query is not working even not effect on any value in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

**UPDATE**

```
\DB::table('subscriptions')
    ->where('business_id', $business_id)
    ->update([
        'package_details' => json_encode(['name' => $package['name'], 'location_count' => $package['location_count']]),
    ]);
```

Comment: dear your query is not working even not effect on any value in db

Comment: Is there an error? I'm basically encoding the array to json in order to be able to store it in DB.

Comment: please tell me why value update like this how to remove curly brac bcz if curly brac insert or update in db so my program will stop working

{"name":"Enterprise","location_count":435345,"user_count":9000}

Comment: According to the image you are storing a json string. That's why there is a curly braces because it is a json